# How do I sanitize a file lookup?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sanitization

My page received a security issue of:

***Stored XSS\Path 1:   (The application's LastTearSheet embeds untrusted data in the generated output with Write, at line 68 of SharedDocs/downloadfiles.aspx.cs. This untrusted data is embedded straight into the output without proper sanitization or encoding, enabling an attacker to inject malicious code into the output. The attacker would be able to alter the returned web page by saving malicious data in a data store ahead of time. The attacker's modified data is then read from the database by the .OrderByDescending method with LastWriteTime, at line 74 of SharedDocs/downloadfiles.aspx.cs. This untrusted data then flows through the code straight to the output web page, without sanitization. This can enable a Stored Cross-Site Scripting (XSS) attack.)


Code Snippet : Code Snippet File Name DocShareB1/downloadfiles.aspx.cs Method .OrderByDescending(f => f.LastWriteTime) .... 74. .OrderByDescending(f => f.LastWriteTime) File Name SharedDocs/downloadfiles.aspx.cs Method private void LastTearSheet() .... 77. Response.Write(myFile)***

The code

```
    private void LastTearSheet()
    {
        var dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(Application["DIR"] + (string)Session["Directory"] + "\\");

        var myFile = dirInfo.GetFiles("*")
            .OrderByDescending(f => f.LastWriteTime)
            .FirstOrDefault();

        Response.Write(myFile);
        string strFilePath = Application["DIR"] + (string)Session["Directory"] + "\\" + myFile;
        DateTime lastModified = System.IO.File.GetLastWriteTime(strFilePath);
        if (lastModified.AddMinutes(10) < DateTime.Now)
        {
            //show download button
            downloadfiles.Visible = true;
        }
        else
        {
            //don't show download button
            downloadfiles.Visible = false;
        }

    }
```

I'm unsure how to "sanitize" this? Seems this is the problem?

```
var myFile = dirInfo.GetFiles("*")
            .OrderByDescending(f => f.LastWriteTime)
            .FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: The first two sentences of the message explain where unsanitized data is being output: `Response.Write(myFile);`

Comment: Yes, it's the myFile variable but how do I modify this code for "sanitization"?

Comment: Try replacing this line... `Response.Write(myFile);` .. with this line `Response.Write(Server.HtmlEncode(myFile));`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Html.Encode in webforms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4018929/how-to-html-encode-in-webforms)

Comment: Thanks quaabaam. I actually tried this: Response.Write(Server.HtmlEncode(myFile.ToString())); as I had a conversion error so needed the .ToString(). I am having the security person rescan and retest. I have no errors so hopefully it's good to go.